# Trying to insert IFERROR formula in Col using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Filters Table for Blanks
Dim lo As ListObject
Dim icol As Long

Set lo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
'Sets Date cleared/voided col
icol = lo.ListColumns(8).Index

lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=icol, Criteria1:="="
lo.ListColumns(8).DataBodyRange.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[CHECK NO.]],Vlookup!D:D,1,0),"")"

End Sub
```

What I am trying to do is update a list for checks that have cleared for the date pulled. 
If it has cleared, enter the date it cleared.

My current manual method is to use vlookup to determine if it has cleared. If there is an error, no data is populated.

I know IFERROR isn't feasible in VBA, it is how I was pulling the date manually. Removing the IFERROR portion pulls the checks that have cleared ok, but I then want to convert all the error/"N/A" to empty cells and those that did not have errors equal to user input date.

Any help in this endeavor is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `""` should be `""""`

Comment: Oh my goodness. Thank you! I have been going around this for hours.  I didn't realize the formula formatting changed like that when transferring to VBA as the formula functioned correctly otherwise.

Comment: Just 2 tips, 1) Try to avoid complete search columns. 2) Avoid whenever possible (it's almost ever possible) IFERROR, it masks all errors, in this case you could use COUNTIF to see if there's no CHECK NO.

Comment: @EvR why?  1.  Vlookup is optimized and there is no difference in speed when using full column in the lookup and just the data set. 2. Using IFERROR in this case it perfectly acceptable and avoids the COUNTIF which is not as optimized as vlookup.  Basicall, both your statements are misleading and in error.

Comment: @Scott Craner in which versions Vlookup is optimized? What if when there's data below or above the data set? What if [CHECK NO.] is already an error? Personally I think masking errors is bad practice, usage of complete columns or rows in formulas is also. And when it comes to speed I don't think you have to place formulas by VBA in cells in the first place.  But just my two cents.

Comment: @EvR I agree 100% on dealing with errors in the data, but this IFERROR is not dealing with errors in the lookup columns it is dealing with there not being a match.  and it is less overhead to use it than to do an `IF` with `COUNTIF`  As far as full columns data should not have different tables on top of one another.  Data should be on its own sheet and kept flattened, In my opinion, then as data grows one does not need to update the formulas.  When using COUNTIF(), SUMIF() AVERAGEIF() or array type formulas, yes it should be limited to the  dataset.  And I agree if using VBA, use VBA.

Comment: @EvR if you want to test it, do this.  In A1 put `=RANDBETWEEN(1,100)` and copy down 15,000 rows.  In B1 put `=VLOOKUP(A1,A:A,1,FALSE)` and fill down the same.  Now hit F9 a few times, the numbers update nearly instantly.  Now in C1 put: `=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)` and fill down the same number of rows.  Now when you hit F9, it takes a second or two to calculate.  That is what I mean.  And eventually with enough COUNTIF()s it will cause the calcs to fail completely but you can fill the full column with VLOOKUP()s and it will not fail.

Comment: @Scott Craner, Tested and yes COUNTIF compared to Vlookup is (very) slow on large datasets, In addition to the use of some matrix formulas and with Getpivotdata formulas, I see there is still a reason to use IFERROR with VLOOKUP and that's speed. I see users use the IFERROR formula, too much and inappropriately, and thereby incur all sorts of mistakes. (maybe IFNA is even better in this case?)